# Identifying whether the user has clicked on a circle or a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api

I have a user-created graphics layer that might have lines, polygons and circles on it. When the user clicks to edit one of the graphics, I would like to be able to identify whether they have clicked on a circle or a polygon but the geometry.type for both of these is "esriGeometryPolygon".

Is there a straightforward way to tell the difference?

Comment: Are they true circles or are they estimated (ie. using 32, 64, 128, etc. points centered around a center). Most basic geometry storage will estimate curves like that, so they *are* polygons in that case. You may have a look at the number of points if you can.

Comment: No, they aren't true circles, they have been created by the drawTool. I thought maybe I could check whether each vertex was the same distance from the centre of the polygon but when I do that, they are coming up with a variance of 1-3 metres so that is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The drawTool has a circle function so you can use that & simply add some attribute declaring its a circle vs polygon.